# What should i do after tutorials

Tags: ros, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I was wondering, what should i do after the firs tutorials to improve my knowledge on ROS ? is there some corrected exercise we can find on the net ? do you think it is interesting to work on some rasberry pi to begin ?
Do you have some cheap hardware "ROS Friendly" to begin to work with ?

Furthermore, do you know some good book to learning efficiently ROS ?
I have the feeling, i'm beggining to know some of the theory, but i still have to practice !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277421/what-should-i-do-after-tutorials/) by [StanSmooth](https://answers.ros.org/users/32748/stansmooth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2017-12-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-06**:
What do you mean by "corrected exercise"?

**Comment by [StanSmooth](https://answers.ros.org/users/32748/stansmooth/) on 2017-12-06**:
I don't know (and that's why i'm here).
For instance having a Gazebo model of a robot, and having to write some publisher to operate a precise function or configurate of a packet for a specific case etc...

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-06**:
Because you used the word "corrected" I thought that you were having trouble with the tutorials, as in they are somehow "incorrect."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While it's good to start your own project, I do recommend you to get some ROS books and play with the code a lot, I've used "Mastering ROS for Robotics Programming" and it's quite good and you can follow their code with their [repo here](https://github.com/qboticslabs/mastering_ros).
It goes quite in depth and guides you towards areas like motion planning, perception, sensor use, arduinos, raspberries and the whole stack, even some ROS Industrial like in the image:
[image: image description]

Also, another piece of beauty is "Programming Robots with ROS" their [repo is here](https://github.com/osrf/rosbook), that book was made by the official maintainers of ROS, the OSRF guys. Be aware that this one is mostly in python, while the Master ROS book is mostly C++, so it's also good to keep that in mind.

I do like Peter's suggestion of getting hands on a project, but it wouldn't hurt at all to play with some already finished products to see how it all goes.

Best of luck!!!

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2017-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [StanSmooth](https://answers.ros.org/users/32748/stansmooth/) on 2017-12-06**:
Thank you ! I was wondering if buying "Mastering ROS for Robotics Programming" worth it !

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My advice to you would be to decide on a robotic project you're interested in and pursue this using ROS to develop your knowledge.

Small mobile robots using the Raspberry Pi are a great place to start, they're small relatively cheap and there are ROS systems all setup and ready to use for them. The [german robots website](http://www.german-robot.com/2016/05/26/raspberry-pi-sd-card-image/) has a link to a raspberry pi image with ubuntu mate and ROS ready to go, you can find it under the heading 'Raspberry Pi 3 Ubuntu with ROS'.

The best way to learn ROS is to use it and to use it you need a project.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2017-12-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [StanSmooth](https://answers.ros.org/users/32748/stansmooth/) on 2017-12-06**:
Thank you I will try that !